# Sketch the region of integration for the integral $\int_{-2}^2 \int_0^{2y} f(x,y)dx\,dy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I am slightly confused when sketching the region for the double integral $$\int_{-2}^2 \int_0^{2y} f(x,y)dx\,dy$$
When I sketch the region I get a triangle in the top right quadrant, however my textbook says the region is two triangles, one in the top right quadrant, one in the bottom left quadrant. I don't understand how this can be if the inequalities for the regions are $0<x<2y$ and $-2<y<2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, as mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Conventions),
$$
\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=-\int_b^af(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
That is, $x$ is between $0$ and $2y$. This means that when $y\lt0$, the range for  $x$ is $2y\lt x\lt0$. Thus,
$$
\int_{-2}^2\int_0^{2y}f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
=\underbrace{\int_0^2\int_0^{2y}f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y}_\text{triangle above the $x$-axis}-\underbrace{\int_{-2}^0\int_{2y}^0f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y}_\text{triangle below the $x$-axis}
$$

Comment: Makes sense now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\limits_{-2}^2 \int\limits_0^{2y} f(x,y)dx\,dy=\underbrace{\int\limits_{-4}^0 \int\limits_{-2}^{\frac{x}{2}} f(x,y)dy\,dx}_\text{left triangle}+\underbrace{\int\limits_{0}^4 \int\limits_{\frac{x}{2}}^{2} f(x,y)dy\,dx}_\text{right triangle}$$